# TextWrangler FInd/Replace with

Tags: regex, replace, textwrangler

I have long lists of location data, which is in XML format.

```
<location><city>London</city><name>Zoo</name><latitude>...</location>
```

Unfortunately the XML is corrupt and I have to replace/fix a lot of
invalid close XML tag occurances. Example, here `</name>` has to be replaced with `</city>`:

```
<location><city>London</name><latitude>...</location>
```

Using TextWrangler Find+Replace I can search for:`<city>[A-Za-z]*</name>`
That statement searches and finds all the invalid lines. So far so good.

Now I want to replace them automatically (Replace All). Normally in regular expressions this is done by defining: `<city>%1</city>` but that is not working. It overwrites the found text, not interpreting the search result nor inserting the value in the `%1` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the in-between characters using capturing group, so that you can reference the captured chars in the replacement part by specifying it's index number like `%1` or `\1` or `$1`

```
<city>([A-Za-z]*)</name>
```

Comment: Works perfectly with the the \1 options. The grouping did the trick! Thanks. (Note: the %1 and $1 don't seem to work)